# What is the meaning of "romped away" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "romped away" in the following sentence

> Chester hugged his mother and romped away. "I love you, too," he
>   seemed to say.

?

Does "Chester hugged his mother and romped away" mean "Chester hugged his mother and ran away" ?

If so, what is the difference in the meaning between "romped away" and "ran away" ?

Comment: Have you lookup up the meaning of *to romp*?

Comment: in my dictionary, the meaning of "romp away" is "to make progress, increase or win quickly and easily", and  the meaning of "romp" is "When children or animals romp, they play noisily and happily."

Comment: The second meaning sounds more likely: he ran away noisily and happily. The author is using one verb to provide a more nuanced meaning for another, but I don't know what this is called.

Comment: If so, does "romp away" mean "play away" ? does "Chester hugged his mother and played away" mean "Chester hugged his mother and ran away nosily and happily" ?

Comment: *Romp* and *play* (and *run*) have different meanings. *Romp* is being substituted for *run* to provide a different meaning, and the implication is that the child ran away, noisily and happily. It is a common (but rather lazy) literary device.

Comment: Which dictionary are you using? You should include that information, and the definition it has, in your question.

Comment: Also, you haven't provided enough context to determine the author's meaning of *romp away*. It could mean either *ran away playfully* or *played noisily and happily*.

Comment: Clare// i use naver english-english dictionary and english-korean dictionary===> http://endic.naver.com/enenIdiom.nhn?sLn=kr&idiomId=a6a46971e30e47b5a33367eafffe763f&query=romp+away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Romp** means to run or play happily or boisterously.

**away** there has the locative sense, departing, moving farther and farther from a place.

P.S. **away** can also mean to do something continuously without interruption, to be engaged in doing something.

> He snored away.
>
> She puttered away in her pottery shed.
>
> He strummed away on a banjo while the infant in its crib cried itself to sleep.

A **romp** is an easy victory.

> They romped over the other team.

But nowadays we (speakers of AmE) don't say "the football team romped **away**". Your dictionary is in error there if it defines "romp away" as "to win quickly and easily" in contemporary American English, where it was used 100 years ago, when college students were wearing raccoon coats.

Comment: In British-english saying a team or player "romped away with it", to mean they won easily, is in common use, at least journalistically.

Comment: It's something not heard in AmE nowadays—at least I've never heard it spoken, and I've been romping on the planet for a while—though "romp" is common enough, most often as a noun. "It was a romp, with Harvard defeating Yale 30-3."  I watch a good deal of English Premier League football, and I don't recall hearing it there—maybe none of the games has been a true romp. How badly does one team have to defeat the other before "romp away" is used?

Comment: [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=romp+away%2Cromp+through%2Cromp+ahead%2Cromp+over%2C+a+romp&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cromp%20away%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cromp%20through%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cromp%20ahead%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cromp%20over%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20romp%3B%2Cc0) shows little use of "romp away" compared to "romp through", which is the other phrasal verb shown in [OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/romp_1) for *romp*.